# Prove that if $A$ is a matrix with $n$ columns then the null space $N(A)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Proposition (3.32). If $A$ is a matrix with $n$ columns then the null
>   space $N(A)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

My attempt:

Suppose we have matrix $\bf A$ with $n$ columns.

Consider arbitrary vector $\bf x$. If $\bf x$ $\in N(A)$, then $\bf x \in \mathbb R^{n}$, because otherwise multiplication $\bf Ax$ won't be possible. Hence $N(A) \subseteq \mathbb R^{n}$.

Required to show closure under vector addition and scalar multiplication.

Consider arbitrary two vectors $\bf w$ and $\bf v$, such that both are in $N(A)$.

We have

$$ \bf Aw = O $$

and

$$\bf Av = O$$

and

$$\bf Aw + Av = O \implies A(w+v) = O$$

Thus vector $\mathbf {w + v} \in N(A)$

Consider arbitrary vector $\bf w$ such that $\mathbf w \in N(A)$  and arbitrary scalar $c$

We have

$$\mathbf A\mathbf w = \bf O$$

Multiply by $c$

$$c \mathbf {Aw} = c \bf O \implies $$

$$\mathbf{A}(c\mathbf{w}) = \bf O $$

Hence vector $c \mathbf w \in N(A)$

Since we have closure under vector addition and scalar multiplication, we conclude that $N(A)$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^{n}$. $\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: This is perfectly correct.

Comment: I believe you also have to show $N(A)$ is nonempty, but otherwise this looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to prove that $0 ∈ N(A)$ (As in the vector $0 ∈ R^n$).

That is trivial of course, because $A0 = O$. Therefore $0 ∈ N(A)$. That with the $2$ properties you already proved is enough to conclude that the null space $N(A)$ is a subspace of $R^n$.